# Recovery admin password

Tags: powerbi, office365

I registered my domain in Office 365, to use PowerBI and Azure and try the Power BI trial period. So I created 2 accounts:

- **contact@mydomain.net** (I made this account admin)
- **support@mydomain.net** (normal account)

However, at a certain moment I went to the account **contact@mydomain.net** (whose access data was saved in the browser and PowerBI Desktop) and I was asked to change the password.

I did the password change process on the run and now I don't remember the password I registered.

I tried the password recovery procedures offered but failed. 
How do I recover my administrator account password?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question. Maybe try http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: But can only posts be made about programming?

Comment: Generally yes, only programming: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Understand. Well, as PowerBI and Office365 tags are not just programming, I think it fits into the category "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"